# Turn camera mode to Black & White

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

How to turn the camera into black & white mode.So I can capture the video in Black & white.

Note:
Without using OpenGL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe  [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) could help:

> The GPUImage framework is a BSD-licensed iOS library that lets you apply GPU-accelerated filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies. In comparison to Core Image (part of iOS 5.0), GPUImage allows you to write your own custom filters, supports deployment to iOS 4.0, and has a simpler interface. However, it currently lacks some of the more advanced features of Core Image, such as facial detection.
>
> GPUImageGrayscaleFilter: Converts an image to grayscale (a slightly faster implementation of the saturation filter, without the ability to vary the color contribution)

Comment: @Anand - Note that this does use OpenGL ES 2.0 behind the scenes, if that matters. However, you don't have to deal with it directly if you use the framework. I know you didn't want to use OpenGL ES, but that's really the only way to achieve the kind of performance required for filtering live video.

Comment: @BradLarson is there any other framework which doesn't use openGL

Comment: @Anand - No, anything that filters video must use OpenGL ES under the hood or performance will be atrocious. Core Image does this, I do this, and others who have their own filtering setups also use OpenGL ES. CPU-bound filtering runs at about 2 FPS for 640x480 frames on an iPhone 4, where Core Image is about 7 FPS, and my framework is well over 60 FPS. As I said, you don't have to touch any of the OpenGL ES API to use this framework, so why avoid it for that reason? The framework does all the work for you under the hood.

Comment: @BradLarson is there an Moire Filter in the GPUImage Framework?

Comment: @meccan - You mean something like interference fringes? Not right now, but you could easily write your own filter for this within the framework based on the posterization filter.